# Python : call function from another class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

Can anyont tell me how to call method from another class?
when i click on `ok` button then i call `def insert(self):` method.I am using code

```
def insert(self):
    #insert data after call add_expense() method
    RowsExpense().add_expense()
```

after insert data i call `RowsExpense().add_expense()`.its calling because `print('llllll')` shows in console.But `self.add_widget(r)` not working because row not showing on screen.

[image]

## demo.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 400)

class User(Popup):
    total_value = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_more()

    def add_more2(self):
        self.ids.rowsExpense.add_expense()

class ExtraPopup(Popup):
    mode = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(ExtraPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_extra(self):
        self.ids.rowsExtra.add_row()

    def insert(self):
        #insert data after call add_expense() method
        RowsExpense().add_expense()


class RowExtra(BoxLayout):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?"])
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    mode = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RowExtra, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.col_data[0] = ''
        self.col_data[1] = ''
        self.col_data[2] = ''


class RowsExtra(BoxLayout):
    #orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    textName = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RowsExtra, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_row(self):
        for x in range(0, 3):
            self.row_count += 1
            r = RowExtra(button_text=str(self.row_count))
            self.add_widget(r)

class Row(BoxLayout):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?", "?", "?"])
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    col_data3 = StringProperty("")
    col_data4 = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_seller_expenses(self):
        self.mode = "Add"
        popup = ExtraPopup(self)
        popup.ids.rowsExtra.textName = self.ids.name.text
        popup.ids.rowsExtra.add_row()
        popup.open()


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_more()

    def add_more(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class RowExpense(BoxLayout):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?"])
    button_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RowExpense, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.col_data[0] = ' '



class RowsExpense(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RowsExpense, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_expense(self):
        print('llllll')
        for x in range(0, 3):
            self.row_count += 1
            r = RowExpense(button_text=str(self.row_count))
            self.add_widget(r)


class rv(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    mode = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(rv, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def add(self):
        self.mode = "Add"
        popup = User()
        popup.open()


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    content_area = ObjectProperty()

    def display(self):
        self.rv = rv()
        self.content_area.add_widget(self.rv)

class demo(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo().run()
```

## demo.kv

```
<Row>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 40

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200

    TextInput:
        id : name
        text: root.col_data3
        width: 300
    TextInput:
        id: number_input
        text: root.col_data4
        width: 300
        input_filter: 'int'

    Button:
        text: "Button"
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200
        on_press: root.add_seller_expenses()


<Rows>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"

<User>:
    id: user
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 5


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            #padding : 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size: 450, 40
            size_hint: None, None

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "Number"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .4
                text: "Value"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

        ScrollView:
            Rows:
                id: rows


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .2
            size_hint_y: .2

            Button:
                text: "+Add More"
                on_press: root.add_more()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: 1, 1

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                padding: 10, 5
                size_hint: .5, 1

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    spacing: 10, 10
                    size: 600, 50
                    size_hint: 1, None

                    Label:
                        text: "SN"
                        text_size: self.size
                        size_hint_x: .3
                        halign: "center"

                ScrollView:
                    RowsExpense:
                        id: rowsExpense

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    size_hint_x: .2
                    size_hint_y: .2

                    Button:
                        text: "+Add More"
                        on_press: root.add_more2()

<rv>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            size_hint: .25, .03
            text: "+Add"
            on_press: root.add()

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 25
            cols: 3

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

<ExtraPopup>:
    title: " Extra"
    title_size: 20
    title_font: "Verdana"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    auto_dismiss: False


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 10, 5
        spacing: 10, 10

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10, 10
            size: 550, 30
            size_hint: 1, None

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .3
                text: "SN"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .7
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

        ScrollView:
            RowsExtra:
                id: rowsExtra

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .3
            size_hint: .15, .1

            Button:
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_extra()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 5
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .2
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}
            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                id: ok_text
                on_release:
                    root.insert()
                    root.dismiss()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                #size_hint_x: .5
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<RowExtra>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 30

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .3
        #top: 200

    TextInput:
        text: root.col_data[1]
        size_hint_x: .7

<RowsExtra>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"


<RowsExpense>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"


<RowExpense>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 30

    TextInput:
        text: root.col_data[0]
        multiline: False



<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (100, 40)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)

<MainMenu>:
    content_area: content_area

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing : 10

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 2

            MenuButton:
                text: 'Menu'
                size : (50, 12)
                on_release: root.display()

        BoxLayout:
            id: content_area
            size_hint_y: 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling class method while You should call instance method instead.

You need to store reference to Your RowsExpense instance in Your root class and run Your method through that reference. Then You can either pass that reference to the class through which You want to run the method  as an argument in it's init function or use plain old:

```
App.get_running_app().root.whateverYouwanttodohere()
```